# What statement means max friendship?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

What does the girl in Laverre City say when the happiness is maxed out?

When I talk to her she says:

> Its amazingly friendly toward you! It must be so happy spending every day with you!

I'm assuming that means max friendship but not sure.

Answer (score 7):

*This answer applies to older versions. I'll still keep it since many google searches may refer here in the future.*

Yes, you can't get any better response, though it does not really mean that you have reached the total maximum (255).

And here is the whole list of possible responses:

- *It doesn't seem to like you at all. It looks mean.* => **`0-69`**
- *You should treat it better. It's not used to you.* => **`70-99`**
- *It's quite cute.* => **`100-149`**
- *It's friendly toward you. It looks sort of happy.* => **`150-199`**
- *I get the feeling that it really trusts you.* => **`200-219`**
- *It looks really happy! It must love you a lot.* => **`220-255`**

[More about friendship.](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friendship)

Comment: Your list doesn't match up with those in X and Y, and overlaps for the final two phrases.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry. This list applies to older versions of pokemon.

Comment: I think the main issue is that you have 200-210 and 200-255

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "It's amazingly friendly towards you! It must be so happy spending every day with you!" is the lady's response if the Pokemon you show her exhibits maximum happiness. I tested this with three cases:

- Talonflame (which I've had since before the 1st badge and is Level 100)
- Pikachu, which I had evolved from a Pichu (evolution only occurs at maximum happiness)
- Umbreon (which Eevee evolves into only when reaching maximum happiness and leveling at night).

In all three cases, that was her response.